# How do I use the 'keyboard' python module in a docker container without an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, keyboard

I am trying to use the python module **keyboard** in a docker container for testing automation that emulates keyboard presses. However, this module continually returns an error in the docker container whereas it works fine in an ubuntu VM.

I have installed different commonly used docker containers and different versions of python. I get the same error. Sadly, google hasn't been as helpful as it usually is here.

Here's an easily reproducible version of what I've done:

```
docker run -t -d -u root --name docker_container python:3.7
echo $(docker exec -u root docker_container bash -c 'python3 -m keyboard' )
```

This returns the below error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py:110: UserWarning: Failed to create a device file using `uinput` module. Sending of events may be limited or unavailable depending on plugged-in devices.
  device = aggregate_devices('kbd')
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/_nixcommon.py", line 106, in start_reading
    self.event_queue.put(device.read_event())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/_nixcommon.py", line 83, in read_event
    data = self.input_file.read(struct.calcsize(event_bin_format))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/_nixcommon.py", line 106, in start_reading
    self.event_queue.put(device.read_event())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/_nixcommon.py", line 83, in read_event
    data = self.input_file.read(struct.calcsize(event_bin_format))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    keyboard.hook(print_event_json)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 459, in hook
    append(callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/_generic.py", line 67, in add_handler
    self.start_if_necessary()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/_generic.py", line 35, in start_if_necessary
    self.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 194, in init
    _os_keyboard.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py", line 114, in init
    build_tables()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py", line 73, in build_tables
    dump = check_output(['dumpkeys', '--keys-only'], universal_newlines=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dumpkeys': 'dumpkeys'
```

From what I understand, it can't access a uinput device / keyboard to be able to dump the keys. Is there a way to virtually simulate a keyboard in the container to allow this to work?

Comment: Hve you tried mounting the device into the container?

Comment: I haven't yet, I'll look into that.

Comment: I'm not finding much on mounting a local keyboard device for the docker container sadly...

Comment: Use the `-v` argument as if you would mount a volume.

Answer (score 0):

try to install the following:

```
apt-get install -y kmod kbd
```

since you need [this](http://kbd-project.org/) to get `dumpkeys`

Comment: Trying this out. I was able to install kmod in the container, but trying to install kbd seems to hang perpetually.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not able to run:
`echo $(docker exec -u root docker_container bash -c 'apt-get install -y kbd' )`
The container returns: 
`debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed`
...and then hangs. :/

I tried an apt-get update and upgrade before as well.

Comment: Ah, I did get it to install using a different docker image. Using 'fullaxx/ubuntu-desktop'. That one may be a more full ubuntu implementation to include the uinput libraries. Continuing to try it out...